# JavaScript Submit and Button

Tags: javascript, java

1.A user is guided through a sequence of web pages, entering details which are then stored in hidden fields until all the user information is finally sent to the server.
Each button on each webpage should be:

```
<input type=button>
<input type=submit>
```

2.A user has to enter some information on a web page. After successful validation, the information is sent to a servlet or CGI script.
The button on the webpage should be:

```
<input type=button>
<input type=submit>
```

There are two scenarios to ask you the difference between ‘submit’ and ‘button’. Can you tell me the best choice for above scenarios and why?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask.... _<input type="submit">_ Defines a submit button (for submitting the form)

Comment: @B001 sorry for not asking clearly, I have posted it again

Comment: _I have posted it again_ No, you have just reformatted the html

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button),
"Note: While input tags of type "button" are still perfectly valid HTML, the newer button tag is now the favored way to create buttons, which has some advantages. It supports the "menu" type, which lets the button serve as the trigger for a popup menu, and given that a button's label text is inserted between the opening and closing tags, you can include HTML in the label, even images."

input type='button', input type='submit', and input type='reset' all create a button on the page. Types submit and reset perform special operations on their form. Type button typically calls some JavaScript to do perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your button to do something (a function with JavaScript or something like that) without the form being submitted use type="button".

If you want your button to submit the form then use type="submit".

Here is some more info on input types
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Answer (score -1):

Basically, that's your homework, and it's not cool, but the general idea here is that storing all the info on the client side and only sending it to the server at the end is:

1. Error-prone.
2. Unsecure
3. The user cannot resume the process from a different browser/computer.